# NewRelicAgent framework crashes in NR_timeElapsedInMilliSeconds

Tags: ios, crash, newrelic

Very often crash appears with following stack:

```
0x000cc1c8  NR_timeElapsedInMilliSeconds in NRTimer.m on Line 54
0x000f70ea  +[NewRelic noticeNetworkRequestForURL:withTimer:responseHeaders:statusCode:bytesSent:bytesReceived:responseData:andParams:] in NewRelic.m on Line 93
0x000cfd7a  __41-[NRURLProtocol handleDidReceiveResponse]_block_invoke in NRURLProtocol.m on Line 431
```

Please can you assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems very likely that this issue is resolved by an update of the New Relic for Mobile Apps iOS SDK. We realize this isn't great news, because updating your app is non-trivial. However, this does look like an issue that is fixed in our most recent agent version: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/ios

Comment: Thank you issue is not reproduced anymore

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to verify that you've got the latest version of the New Relic for Mobile Apps iOS SDK. After that, you'll probably need to get in touch at support.newrelic.com. For a crash like this one, New Relic will ask for the following information (I'm happy to let you know what information New Relic will probably need to investigate, but I don't think all this info is necessarily appropriate to post publicly, so do use a support ticket at support.newrelic.com):

1) I'd like to get a sense of the scope of this issue: was it reported for a single user, multiple users, or is this consistent and replicable in your development environment?

2) A crash log with symbols is helpful for initial troubleshooting, and several third party error reporting services (Crashlytics, TestFlight, Airbrake, etc.) will provide useful stack traces. Please paste any stack traces if you have them. If you're using Apple's crash reports service, you can do the following:

- Log in to https://itunesconnect.apple.com
- Go to "Manage Your Applications"
- Choose your application by clicking on its name
- Click the "View details" button under the Versions table
- Click "Crash Reports" link
- If you don't see any reports, press "refresh"

3) If this can be replicated in your dev environment, I'd like to run some logging from the New Relic for Mobile Apps iOS SDK during the crash. Turn up the logging level in the app by adding this method call before calling startWithApplicationToken:

[NRLogger setLogLevels:NRLogLevelALL];

To make this change take effect, hit “Run” in Xcode and let the iOS Simulator launch. Copy and paste the entire contents of the simulator or device console output while running the app. (press Shift-Command-C to show the debug console in Xcode).

4) Also, please attach your AppDelegate.m to this ticket so that we can take a closer look at how you’ve implemented the New Relic agent in your app. You can find the location of the file by selecting it in the application's project in Xcode, then choosing File > Show in Finder.

5) Finally, please include a permalink to the where the app is reporting to the New Relic user interface. To create a permalink to any page within the New Relic user interface, scroll to the bottom and click 'Permalink ∞' all the way on the right next to 'Kiosk Mode.' This will show us the exact page and time period that you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

@Toby_New_Relic, please find answers below

1) It reproduces not just on one device. As I see it is only iPhone 5S.

2) Stack:

```
2   libsystem_platform.dylib    0x38284722  _sigtramp
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x38289a52  pthread_kill
4   libsystem_c.dylib   0x381d302c  abort
5   libsystem_c.dylib   0x381b2c6a  __assert_rtn
6   MyApp   0x000bd760  NR_timeElapsedInMilliSeconds in NRTimer.m on Line 54
7   MyApp   0x000e8682  +[NewRelic noticeNetworkRequestForURL:withTimer:responseHeaders:statusCode:bytesSent:bytesReceived:responseData:andParams:] in NewRelic.m on Line 93
8   MyApp   0x000c1312  __41-[NRURLProtocol handleDidReceiveResponse]_block_invoke in NRURLProtocol.m on Line 431
9   MyApp   0x000e0c78  __NR__dispatch_async_block_invoke in NRGCDOverride.m on Line 38
10  libdispatch.dylib   0x381570c2  _dispatch_call_block_and_release
11  libdispatch.dylib   0x3815c7d8  _dispatch_root_queue_drain
12  libdispatch.dylib   0x3815c9c4  _dispatch_worker_thread2
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x38286dfe  _pthread_wqthread
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x38286cc3  start_wqthread
```

3) I can't replicate this issue on dev env

4)

I just added to pch

`#import <NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h>`

and to application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

`[ NewRelicAgent startWithApplicationToken: <APPLICATION_TOKEN> ];`

5) Permalink

https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/47982